# Using PREPARE command(SQL) vs PDO or mysqli function

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli, prepared-statement

I develop web applications using PHP and use MySQL as the database. I am trying to understand the usage of prepared statements and am just taking my first steps.

As I understand it, prepared statements are primarily to:

1. Increase the efficiency of the query(pre-parsing, cached execution plan, binary data transfer between client and server)
2. Ensure protection from code injection attacks (not entirely clear on this, but I think I have a basic understanding)

(may be there are other uses as well)

The question is,

why not just use the PREPARE statement that MySQL provides and make your prepared statements before hand and then use those in your PHP application, either PDO or mysqli? Better yet, make stored procedures using these prepared statements and expose only those to the PHP programmers?

This way, the actual burden of making the correct queries is separated / handled by the database programmer. PHP programmer can completely focus only on the application implementation and optimization.

I don't foresee any changes in the database that I would be using anytime soon. MySQL meets all the requirements. But just to keep my application clean and DB agnostic, I could use PDO. Or stick to procedural coding and do mysqli

Is this a valid / tried and tested approach to go about building an application?

Thanks

Comment: Lol, almost every assumption in your question is false :) 1. As you can see, efficiency is more imaginable than real. 2. As for the security, it's just another way from escaping, not really big difference. Mysqli has object oriented interface as well and PDO will not let you to interchange database engines so easily.

Comment: I have done little more reading and found that the statements that are prepared using PREPARE are only session specific. So can someone tell me if PDO prepared statements are also for specific session? And each page request in PHP is one session (as far as the DB is concerned - open connection and close connection), correct?

Answer (score 1):

The result of the PREPARE statement is somewhat special and is not returnable to the user. You can use it by storing in a variable of course in MySQL. But, that's not standard. MySQL gives you APIs so that the PDO driver utilizes them and you can write DB agnostic code. I see totally no reason not to do that. Among the many things using PDO I particularly like [DBTNG](https://github.com/crell/dbtng) (Drupal 7 DB layer spinned off) because I had a part in writing it :) and [idiorm](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm).